# I can't connect to new router with same ssid that the older router

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I have a problem with my wifi in Ubuntu (15.04). Recently, i have changed my wifi routers. Due to differents devices that was already configured, I have configured the new router with the same SSID and password, and this have worked for other devices but not for my Notebook with Ubuntu (in windows 7 in the same notebook it works!).

Intriguinly, If I change the SSID of my router network,  it works in Ubuntu, but i don't want to change my SSID, because i have a lot of devices with this ssid/password stored.

Why i can connect to my network except when the ssid is the same of my old network?

Please, How can i fix my problem? Does someone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every connection has a configuration file stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory. Sometimes those files get corrupt and you cannot reconnect to the same network even though seemingly the file has all the info - password,essid,etc.

So removing the specific file and reconnecting again, should help your case. For instance, `sudo rm "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/My Network Name"`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I don't know which step is really need, but it's what i have done, in order:

1. Remove wi-fi connections from network manager that has that ssid (i
   was tried create another one)
2. remove the files of that connections
   from /etc/NetworkManager/connections/[NAME OF CONNECTION]
3. reboot
4. login with the original admin user (i was trying with another admin
   user before) and Connect! Now works =)